# Telerik RadWindow Javascript return values to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback, telerik, return-value

I have a parent page that launches a telerik radwindow and passes it an argument.

Once the radwindow is done processeing the value, I need it to return it to the parent page, and I would like the parent page to have access to this value in my code behind page.

I have tried to pass the value to a hidden field on my page and then trigger a page refresh and my code behind watches to see if the value is working.

I can't seem to get this to work. I get the return value in the parent javascript, but i can't get it from my hidden field from the code behind.

I even get it into the text box like i need to but, when i find the Hidden field in the codebehind, there is no value set.

Where I have set alerts, I am getting the values displayed as i need to.

I suspect that the reason I can't see my return value in the code behind file, is that when the page is refreshed, I am getting a new page and not only causing a post back.

And is there not a better way i can do this.

here is my code in the parent page:

Parent ASPX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenWnd() {
        var oWnd = radopen(null, "RadWindow1");
    }
    function OnClientShow(oWnd) {
        //Create a new Object to be used as an argument to the radWindow
        var arg = new Object();
        //Using an Object as a argument is convenient as it allows setting many properties.
        arg.text = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        //Set the argument object to the radWindow  
        oWnd.Argument = arg;
    }

    function ClientCallBackFunction(radWindow, returnValue) {
        //check if a value is returned from the dialog
        if (returnValue.newtext) {
            document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = returnValue.newtext;
            alert("HiddenValue: " + document.getElementById("Hidden1").value);
        }
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<div>
    <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager2" runat="server">
        <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" OnClientShow="OnClientShow" ClientCallBackFunction="ClientCallBackFunction"
                NavigateUrl="Dialog2.aspx" />
        </Windows>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="button" value="Send content to dialog page" onclick="OpenWnd()" />
<p>
    <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
</p>
</form>
```

Parent Code Behind:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlInputHidden hidden = (HtmlInputHidden)Page.FindControl("Hidden1");

        if (IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hidden.Value))
        {
          //Code Here
        }
    }
```

Here is my Dialog code:

Dialog ASPX:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }
        function ConfigureDialog() {
            //Get a reference to the radWindow wrapper
            var oWindow = GetRadWindow();
            //Obtain the argument 
            var oArg = oWindow.Argument;
            //Use the argument
            var oArea = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            oArea.value = oArg.text;
        }
        function SendAndClose() {
            var oWindow = GetRadWindow();
            //Get current content of text area
            var arg = new Object();
            arg.newtext = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
            oWindow.Close(arg);
            RefreshParentPage();
        }
        function RefreshParentPage() {
            GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.location.reload();

            alert("RefreshParentPage");
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks for all the help

Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the following

```
GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.location.reload();
```

But that wont cause a postback it will simply reload the parent page, you need to cause a potback.
You could try adding a button to the parent form with the style set 'display:none', and handling the click event in the code behind, you can fire this button off from your js code.

In Parent Page :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnClick" Style="display:none"    OnClick="btnClick_Click"/>

protected void btnClick_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     string val = this.Hidden1.Value; //Code goes here
}
```

You can invoke from your javascript like this (non jQuery), place this in your callback

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnClick.ClientID').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be this on the aspx side:

`<%=this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new System.Web.UI.PostBackOptions(btnClick))%>`